# Screen rotation lock not working

Tags: 8.1, screen

This is not an issue but I guess a bug in my Windows phone. I found this in my Lumia 520 which has Windows phone OS 8.1(Developer's Preview) and I don't know if this is the case with Windows Phone OS 8.0 phones.

Bug:

 When I go to Settings → about, then my screen rotation lock(Set to locked, portrait) does not seem to work.

Is this a bug in my phone or is it in all the Windows Phones?

Comment: You better report it to developers. http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us

Comment: Confirmed on Lumia 920 with 8.1 preview - Settings → About doesn't respect rotation lock.

Comment: Yes, it's the bug that happened on my Nokia Lumia 920 as well.

Comment: In my 920 it worked. From settings and from action center too.

Comment: Does this happen everywhere, or only in certain apps?

Comment: This happens in about page under Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a bug that should be [reported to Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=winphoneosissues&filter=alltypes&sort=firstpostdesc&brandIgnore=true)